# pandera says that it has no attribute 'validate'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I am trying to validate an excel sheet.  This is my schema and validation code.  According to the documentation it should just be as simple as calling the validate function and it would print any errors, but it is not working for me.  I have made sure the schema is a valid json file.  I keep getting
"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dev_projects/main2.py", line 57, in <module>
    errors = validate_schema(df,schema)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/dev_projects/app_functions/validation.py", line 47, in validate_schema
    schema.validate(df, lazy=True)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'validate'
"
validation snipet
```

```
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    print(f'validating {sheet_name}')
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)

    # check if schema exists
    schema_file = (os.path.join(schema_folder, f'{sheet_name}.json'))
    print(f'the schema file is {schema_file}')
    if not os.path.exists(schema_file):
        print('no schema file found')

    # load schema
    try:
        with open(schema_file, "r") as f:
            schema = json.load(f)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f'Error decoding json in {schema_file}: {e.msg} at line {e.lineno}, column {e.colno}')

    try:
        schema.validate(df, lazy=True)
    except pa.errors.SchemaError as e:
        print(e)
```

schema.json

```
{
  "schema_type": "dataframe",
  "version": "0.13.4",
  "columns": {
    "mgmt_vip": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4_address",
          "coerce": true,
          "error":  "Value is not a valid IP Address"
        }
      ],
      "unique": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "mgmt_gw": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4_address",
          "coerce": true,
          "error":  "Value is not a valid IP Address"
        }
      ],
      "unique": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "ce_name": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "domain": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "condition",
          "condition": "lamda x: '.' in x and x.count('.') >= 2 and x[0] != '.' and x[-1] != '.'",
          "error": "Value is not an FQDN"
        }
      ],
      "unique": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "Location": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "unique": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "Radius1": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4_address",
          "coerce": true,
          "error":  "Value is not a valid IP Address"
        }
      ],
      "unique": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "Radius2": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4_address",
          "coerce": true,
          "error":  "Value is not a valid IP Address"
        }
      ],
      "unique": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "Radius_Pw": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "unique": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "routing_engine": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "isin",
          "isin": ["local", "remote"],
          "error": "Value must be local or remote"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Montitoring_IP": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "checks": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4_address",
          "coerce": true,
          "error":  "Value is not a valid IP Address"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Rest_User": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "unique": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "Rest_Password": {
      "dtype": "str",
      "nullable": false,
      "unique": false,
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have spent several hours on this and cant get the schema to validate, It keeps giving me an error that there is no validate attribute